# Trackpad writing in Chinese on unix?

Tags: linux, macos, touchpad, chinese, ime

I've seen the trackpad tool to write chinese characters on macs, is there any such linux clone? Or are there any projects that anyone knows of which are trying to create that for linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ibus-handwrite](http://code.google.com/p/ibus-handwrite/)

[tomoe](http://tomoe.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/en/blog/index.rb)